# how to add this html code into the append code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

So I have the following html code:

```
<div> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script> 
</div>
```

Please take a look at the actual code run in the browser. It shows a link.

I want to add the link to an navigation bar with the following code:

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 $('nav ul').append('<li><a onClick="test()" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a></li>');
}
</script>
```

But I'm not managing to add the code within the append correctly. How do I reference the js source and call the xMinicart function within the append code?

Thanks a lot!

**super important update!**

It's almost there! the following javascript code does work in jsfiddle but it doesn't work in squarespace. I'm not sure why.

```
$('nav ul').append('<li id="hello">test</li>');

$.getScript("https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118", function(){
    xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini","id=hello");
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/8/

Comment: are you wanting the `xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini");` in the newly added `ul` element?

Comment: @whodeee yes! I need the xMinicart and its source within the ul element through the append code

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use jQuery's getScript function

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

So you would load the URL and then use the callback to execute the code

```
<script>
var url = "https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118";
$.getScript( url, function() {
   var s = document.createElement('script');
   s.innerText = 'xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini");'
   $('nav ul').append(s);       
});
</script>
```

Comment: hmm ok but how do I add this whole thing into the ul element through the append code?

Comment: @user3507859 check out my edit. You create a script element, set the inner text then append.

Comment: it looks like it's almost there, the added link loads (because there in an animation when it loads) but it's not visible

Comment: I edited my original post - I added the original append code. maybe it has something to do with the link not being visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of my other answer, here's a JSFiddle I tried

http://jsfiddle.net/W2pQA/1

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('ul').append('<li><a onClick="test()" href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a></li>');

    var url = "https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118";

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = url;

    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.innerText = 'xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini");'
    $('ul').append(script).append(s);  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work; Have you seen what the first code shows? I mean the <div> one. It shows a link. I would like that link inside the navigation bar, I think I got you confused with the test() function, I'm sorry. Please check out the result from the simple <div> code. I'm trying to get that exact link IN the nav bar

Comment: check this out please http://jsfiddle.net/g5Fbr/ See the first link? (the one which says "sacola de compras") that's exactly what I need, but below "link 2", it doesn't have to be called "link 3", I just want it to be placed below "link 2" within the nav bar.. does it help?

Comment: @user3507859 Check out my edited JSFiddle and code above. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: thank you for helping. I'm not sure what your jsfiddle does, it seems the javascript function is called but the link doesn't appear. I got it to work on jsfiddle but it doesn't work in Squarespace, I'm not sure why! I'll edit my original post with the code

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the JS you're trying to execute is trying to run before the external JS file has completed loading.

I modified your latest JSFiddle to wait for the external file to load, then when finished, execute the xMiniCart code:

http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/9/

```
$('nav ul').append('<li id="hello">test</li>');

var script = $.getScript("https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118");
$.when(script).then(function(){
   xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini","id=hello"); 
});
```

Here's some documentation on the `$.when` code above:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/